# How to keep TensorFlow open between inferences in server

Tags: php, android, python, tensorflow, server

We're trying to use TensorFlow (TF) on a server for inference on an image.

The android app sends the jpeg image to my machine, the php api execute my android inference (python) script and return the scores, it takes about 6s, but we realize that it takes a long time to load TF, but a short time to make the inference, for example one request takes 10% of resources, another one 10% so it has 20% only for two inferences at same time, and two TF models.

We want load only one TF instance in background:

1. A device send the jpeg, and pass it to TF.
2. B device send the jpeg, and pass it to TF.
3. TF takes first A, and second B, and makes the inferece in sequence.
4. return scores.

For a same moment of time the server has load only 1 instance of TF.

What we are doing:

1. A device send the jpeg, load TF instance, make inference and pass it to TF.
2. B device send the jpeg, load TF instance, make inference and pass it to TF.
3. For a same moment of time, the server has load *n instances* , 2 in this case, of TensorFlow, instead only one.

Were calling TensorFlow in php with 
api.php

```
shell_exec("python3 myinferece.py image=image_path")
```

and the TF inference with:
inference.py

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
scores = sess.run(our_params)
```

The final code is deploy in aws.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish the task of keeping TensorFlow running and accepting multiple inference requests, you're going to need some form of inter-process communication.

For example, you could make the TF Python program wait for new inputs via a pipe while the PHP program sent those values the pipe every time a new request came in.

Giving a complete example for every type of inter-process communication (pipes, sockets) feels out of the scope of this question, but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much for you effort, you give us a great idea. If you maybe had near your hand some source code or example will be great!

Comment: @BigPoppa if I gave you a great idea, maybe accept my answer?

Comment: Yeah Ofc, but we made with your socket idea, and we have fast af inferences times, but I wanna know what were you about to say